# Firebase Crashlytics Error during Initialisation

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, crashlytics

Based on this link [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0)

I have added my project in firebase console, added Firebase Crashlytics dependency and google-services.json to my android studio project.

i have added  **Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());** in my launch activity, but when i run the project it shows below error

```
This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you add this line to the top of your build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```